# Print separate paragraph while user is taking pause for certain time limit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, setinterval

I am building Voice to text app in React.js using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition#developing.

I want to detect whether user is giving a pause and print it as a separate paragraph.

I tried to add a particular string (for instance '12') after some interval of time in the wordArray using setInterval() function:

```
    var text = transcript;  // From useSpeechRecognition()
    let wordArray = [];     // To store all words separately

    text.split(" ").forEach(word => {
        wordArray.push(word);
    });

    function update(){
        wordArray.push('12');
    }

    const timer = setInterval(update,4000);

    console.log(wordArray);
```

But it is not appending the values.
My idea is to add '/n' to where ever the particular string is present.
Please share your other opinions to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.